# C CreateProcess wait for fully load memory

Tags: c, buffer, portable-executable, bad-alloc, readprocessmemory

What method to CreateProcess UPX wait for fully load memory and suspened for ReadProcessMemory

```
   PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;
   STARTUPINFO startupInfo;

   memset(&processInformation, 0, sizeof(processInformation));
   memset(&startupInfo, 0, sizeof(startupInfo));
   startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
   startupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_NORMAL;

   CreateProcess(L"upx.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);

    WaitForSingleObject(processInformation.hProcess, 50); //help me next wait load fully memory

    suspend(processInformation.dwProcessId);

    WriteProcessMemory................

    resume(processInformation.dwProcessId);
```

Comment: I don't get this, and I assume I'm not the only one. Please try to ask a comprehensible question. Also state what your *real goal* is.

Comment: When open upx, i need wait uncompress all => suspended process => readprocess memory

Comment: no way. upx unpacker not fire any events  or do something special after it unpack original image, before pass control to it. only under debugger, manually, you can catch this moment. possible inject dll on create, which internally hook some api and catch when unpack finished.